# Clash of clans link problems

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have my CoC account on my android phone and my wife's iPad, my android broke and I now own an iPhone with a different Apple ID. It will not let me link the new phone be it says I already linked the account once..but I don't have the old phone anymore so how can I link it to the new phone. Pulling my hair out here!

Comment: this is probably something you should contact supercell support for

Comment: Isn't there a "link limit" limiting the number of devices you can link to? If i'm not mistaken that limit is 2.

Comment: Try connecting with Supercell ID

Answer (score 0):

In game if you click the settings button and use link devices then follow them instructions rather then trying to connect your gamecenters together. Also having the same apple ID but different game centre ID's confuses the game sometimes too. Also try waiting a bit because the servers muck up sometimes and wont let you link devices otherwise are you sure the game is both on the same update as each other?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and went into the help built into the Clash of Clans game and told SuperCell Support about the issue. They went though their confirmation process and removed the link on their server for me.